# The solution to a Cauchy-Euler differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

**Problem statement**: Assume that $y=x^2 \ln (x)$ is a solution to the differential equation
$ x^2y'' +axy' +by=0$. What is the value of $a+2b$?

**Solution attempt**: It is known that a Cauchy-Euler equation has a solution of the form $y=cx^m\ln(x)$ if the characteristic polynomial of the equation has a repetitive root. The polynomial is:
$$m(m-1) + am +b= m^2 + (a-1)m +b= 0. $$
To force repetitive roots, the so-called delta has to equal $0$. That is,
$$ (a-1)^2-4b=0\Rightarrow (a-1)^2 = 4b \Rightarrow a-1 = \pm 2b. $$
The last equation in particular implies $a+2b = 1. \square$

However, my solution manual says that $a+2b = 5$ without providing the details. Can you help me understand this?

Comment: Note that you wrote $(a-1)^{2}=4b\implies a-1=\pm 2b$ instead of $\pm 2\sqrt{b}$.

Comment: You should be able to get $a + 2b = 5$ directly by substituting the given solution into the differential equation.  Maybe not the intended solution, but straightforward.

Comment: Take a few derivatives of any trial function, in your case $x^2 \log x$, plug ’em into your equation and work out what the values of $a$ and $b$ would have to be. Time to roll up your sleeves.

Comment: @xXACEXx Silly me! That was a fatal mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ m^2 + (a-1)m +b= 0.$$
Since $m=2$ is a solution we deduce that:
$$b=-2(1+a)$$
The disctiminant is zero $\Delta=0 $:
$$(a-1)^2-4b=0$$
$$(a-1)^2+8(a+1)=0$$
$$(a+3)^2=0$$
$$ \implies a=-3$$
$$(a,b)=(-3,4)$$
And
$$a+2b=5$$